# sqlsrv_query never returns

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have the above `mysql query`, on PHP:

```
$get_image = "SELECT PHOTO FROM Items WHERE CODE =CAST(".$image_code." AS varchar )";
$new_image_result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $get_image);
```

I have limited access on the database (which is a mess), with an SQL view. Everything I need from the DB is functioning great, except the photos where they are stored in blob form. I can retrieve the photos from most of the items but there are some items that my query doesn't return at all. I have retrieved photos that are stored in blob sized from `5kb to 3mb`.

Whenever I execute the above query some item's photos do never return and my script stops waiting the query to return (I have set the execution time to more than 200 seconds and still not returning).

Is there a way to know what is the problem and the query stucks (sqlsrvr errors don't work)?

Can I overrun the problem (set executions on time limit to sqlsrvr or to PHP function, so ignore the query return and do stuff above)?

Is there something I miss?

Comment: For starters you should specify the size of your varchar. When you don't state the size it uses the default size which in this case would be 30, but in other cases it would be 1. You also really should use parameterized queries. My guess on the performance is because you have to search all images in the table. Can you use a PhotoID or something other column that doesn't force sql server to search through each and every image?

Comment: CODE refers to one exact item on my table which has 0 or one photo. i have about 9000 items, 2-3000 of them have no photo, most of the other have photos and i can get them, but there are about 200-300 items that they stuck the query when they run for the photo. i put varchar to see if there is problem in this field, ignoring it like "SELECT PHOTO FROM rp_eshopItems WHERE CODE =$image_code" runs the same in all the items but  i have the same output for those 200-300->no output!

Comment: I understand it is one row in the table. Keep in mind I can't see your screen, I have no idea what your table structure, what you are trying to do or what the actual issue is here. I am guessing based on a vague description of the problem and my experience with things I have encountered. Perhaps this would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is it always the same rows you cannot retrieve?  Can you run the query for a problem row directly in [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)?  Have you tried using [SQL Server's Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to trace a problem query?

Comment: well, silly me, i set the execution time to 500 seconds and i had results. It seems that there is a photo stored in blob form which its resized 50% .jpeg is 11.2mb. I think that is the cause of the mystery.